# I can not use google api java client YouTubeSample in android app

Tags: android, google-api

I just want get my video playUrl in android....
I have checked the relevant issues about use YouTubeSample in android ,Their answer is yes
But when i run my code in emulator or my android device it does not work
my code is:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleTransport;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.*;
    import com.google.api.client.http.*;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class main extends Activity {
     HttpTransport transport;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Debug.enableLogging();
            try {
              try {
                HttpTransport transport = setUpTransport();
                showVideos(transport);
              } catch (HttpResponseException e) {

                throw e;
              }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
              t.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        private static HttpTransport setUpTransport() {
            HttpTransport transport = GoogleTransport.create();
            GoogleHeaders headers = (GoogleHeaders) transport.defaultHeaders;
            headers.setApplicationName("Google-YouTubeSample/1.0");
            headers.gdataVersion = "2";
            transport.addParser(new JsonCParser());
            return transport;
          }

          private static VideoFeed showVideos(HttpTransport transport)
              throws IOException {
            //View.header("Get Videos");
            // build URL for the video feed for "search stories"
            YouTubeUrl url = YouTubeUrl.forVideosFeed();
            url.author = "cecol3500123";
            // execute GData request for the feed
            VideoFeed feed = VideoFeed.executeGet(transport, url);
            //View.display(feed);
            return feed;
          }
    }
```

I compile it ok ,but on the device just get **the application main has stopped unexpectedly**

I found I always stopped on code:`HttpTransport transport = GoogleTransport.create();`

The AndroidManifest has set permission :
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

And my project has **google api java client library**. 
    What I set, is it okay?
    I have tried all possible(I had modified the code, again and again) .
    I do not know how to do.
    Please help me ,I just want get my video playUrl in android....
    (Or can someone give me right code ? )  .
    sorry for my poor English

```
renew with debug trace
this is my program Debug trace                             
11-23 09:45:10.466: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f0700e5                                 
11-23 09:45:10.486: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020031        
11-23 09:45:10.496: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020030        
11-23 09:45:10.506: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f050000       
11-23 09:45:10.716: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060000            
11-23 09:45:10.856: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060001                       
11-23 09:45:11.866: DEBUG/ddm-heap(180): Got feature list request    
11-23 09:45:12.166: DEBUG/ddm-heap(185): Got feature list request                
11-23 09:45:12.526: DEBUG/ddm-heap(165): Got feature list request               
11-23 09:45:12.716: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f0700e5                             
11-23 09:45:12.756: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020031                                
11-23 09:45:12.767: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020030                           
11-23 09:45:12.776: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f050000                       
11-23 09:45:12.796: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060000                        
11-23 09:45:12.826: WARN/ResourceType(62): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060001     
11-23 09:45:13.286: DEBUG/ddm-heap(143): Got feature list request    
11-23 09:45:13.646: WARN/BackupManagerService(62): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.providers.settings' uid=10017      
11-23 09:45:13.946: WARN/BackupManagerService(62): dataChanged but no participant pkg='com.android.providers.settings' uid=10017    
11-23 09:45:14.426: DEBUG/dalvikvm(62): GC freed 8344 objects / 558776 bytes in 461ms    
11-23 09:45:14.826: INFO/ActivityManager(62): Start proc com.android.email for broadcast     com.android.email/com.android.exchange.BootReceiver: pid=205 uid=10023 gids={3003, 1015}
11-23 09:45:14.836: INFO/ActivityManager(62): Starting activity: Intent {        act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.testcom/.main }        
11-23 09:45:15.066: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(185): Shutting down VM          
11-23 09:45:15.076: DEBUG/dalvikvm(185): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit           
11-23 09:45:15.106: DEBUG/dalvikvm(185): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down    
11-23 09:45:15.106: DEBUG/dalvikvm(185): HeapWorker thread shutting down    
11-23 09:45:15.116: DEBUG/dalvikvm(185): HeapWorker thread has shut down     
11-23 09:45:15.127: DEBUG/jdwp(185): JDWP shutting down net...    
11-23 09:45:15.127: INFO/dalvikvm(185): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries               
11-23 09:45:15.147: DEBUG/dalvikvm(185): VM cleaning up            
11-23 09:45:15.226: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(185): ERROR: thread attach failed         
11-23 09:45:15.496: DEBUG/dalvikvm(185): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 639500 of 5242880 (12%)          
11-23 09:45:15.566: WARN/ActivityManager(62): Activity pause timeout for     HistoryRecord{43cec138 com.android.launcher/.Launcher}     
11-23 09:45:15.676: INFO/ActivityManager(62): Start proc com.testcom for activity     com.testcom/.main: pid=210 uid=10027 gids={3003, 1015}   
11-23 09:45:16.266: DEBUG/ddm-heap(205): Got feature list request   
11-23 09:45:16.786: DEBUG/ddm-heap(210): Got feature list request   
11-23 09:45:16.976: DEBUG/dalvikvm(30): GC freed 284 objects / 10848 bytes in 1262ms   
11-23 09:45:17.517: DEBUG/dalvikvm(30): GC freed 50 objects / 2224 bytes in 410ms   
11-23 09:45:17.647: INFO/dalvikvm(210): Could not find method    com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleTransport.create, referenced from method com.testcom.main.setUpTransport     
11-23 09:45:17.657: WARN/dalvikvm(210): VFY: unable to resolve static method 4:     Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleTransport;.create ()Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport;
11-23 09:45:17.657: DEBUG/dalvikvm(210): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0009    
11-23 09:45:17.677: DEBUG/dalvikvm(210): Making a copy of Lcom/testcom/main;.setUpTransport code (128 bytes)    
11-23 09:45:17.687: WARN/dalvikvm(210): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport;)
11-23 09:45:17.697: WARN/dalvikvm(210): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/testcom/YouTubeUrl; (6)
11-23 09:45:17.777: WARN/dalvikvm(210): Link of class 'Lcom/testcom/YouTubeUrl;' failed   
11-23 09:45:17.777: INFO/dalvikvm(210): Could not find method     com.testcom.YouTubeUrl.forVideosFeed, referenced from method com.testcom.main.showVideos
11-23 09:45:17.787: WARN/dalvikvm(210): VFY: unable to resolve static method 40:     Lcom/testcom/YouTubeUrl;.forVideosFeed ()Lcom/testcom/YouTubeUrl;
11-23 09:45:17.787: DEBUG/dalvikvm(210): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0007    
11-23 09:45:17.826: DEBUG/dalvikvm(210): Making a copy of Lcom/testcom/main;.showVideos code (56 bytes)    
11-23 09:45:17.867: WARN/dalvikvm(210): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport;)      
11-23 09:45:17.877: WARN/dalvikvm(210): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport;)      
11-23 09:45:17.927: WARN/dalvikvm(210): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 13 (Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpResponseException;)   
11-23 09:45:17.937: WARN/dalvikvm(210): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x13     
11-23 09:45:17.947: WARN/dalvikvm(210): VFY:  rejected Lcom/testcom/main;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V     
11-23 09:45:17.957: WARN/dalvikvm(210): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0013    
11-23 09:45:17.957: WARN/dalvikvm(210): VFY:  rejected Lcom/testcom/main;.onCreate     (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
11-23 09:45:18.017: WARN/dalvikvm(210): Verifier rejected class Lcom/testcom/main;    
11-23 09:45:18.017: WARN/dalvikvm(210): Class init failed in newInstance call     (Lcom/testcom/main;)
11-23 09:45:18.027: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(210): Shutting down VM     
11-23 09:45:18.037: WARN/dalvikvm(210): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
11-23 09:45:18.047: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception     
11-23 09:45:18.107: DEBUG/dalvikvm(30): GC freed 2 objects / 48 bytes in 568ms    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210): java.lang.VerifyError: com.testcom.main    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at    java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)   
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)   
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)       
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)    
11-23 09:45:18.167: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(210):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)    
11-23 09:45:18.237: INFO/ActivityThread(205): Publishing provider    com.android.email.provider: com.android.email.provider.EmailProvider
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey ,everybody(just only two people)
I have found the problem is my library path is not right 
The compile classpath is right but the runtime classpath is wrong in eclipse
Although I do not know how the case
My solution is add .jar file under the project directly instead of creating an user library(which includes .jar file) and add it to project
So,the youtubesample can run on android but you need to pay attention to classpath settings

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to the permissions.

I suspect that what is going on is that you have com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleTransport on your compile classpath, but not the runtime classpath.  Or perhaps you are compiling against one version, but running against another version of the library.

This happens to me for example when I use Maven, which for some reason is not honored when running via Eclipse.  You have to make sure the dependency on the google-api-java-client package is explicitly specified in the .classpath.

Comment: So the problem is when my program running ,it cannot link to google api java clent lib,but i had set all lib in classpath,what I need to adjust ? (thank you for your answer,sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0):

You have certainly to add something like:

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.something" />
```

in your manifest (i don't know what the something is for google transport)

Comment: In fact,my AndroidManifest has setted:"android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS","android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS","android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS","com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH","com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.youtube",,What is my lack of it?

Comment: I've edited my post, i'm new in stackoverflow and i dont see that the interrested part does not appear !  You probably miss somme uses-library

Comment: Is add <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.something" />? i have just test my code with your Recommended,But it also not work as before,Is problem in AndroidManifest file?(but thank you for your answer)

Comment: Replace "something" by what do you need ! (ex: maps, etc...), but i don't know if it's needed for youtube.   If you show me your debug trace (output of adb logcat) i can certainly help more.

Comment: I have post my program debug trace

Comment: My YouTubeUrl class is under the package which is same package with the main class,,, The YouTubeUrl class is same as YouTubeSample YouTubeUrl (url:http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/youtube-jsonc-sample/?repo=samples#youtube-jsonc-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/youtube/model)

Comment: I find error maybe is this "11-23 09:45:17.647: INFO/dalvikvm(210): Could not find method com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleTransport.create, referenced from method com.testcom.main.setUpTransport"Because it was the first problems encountered in the program,   But the GoogleTransport.create() method is defined in the google api java client lib,and my project had include the lib,   So i do not know how to resolve it....

Comment: I can't find any information in the android api about GoogleTransport, you certainly need a third part api (like this: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/ )

Comment: This is GoogleTransport api "http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.2.1-alpha/index.html" The gdata api is incompatible with android environment.....(i have test many times)

Comment: You certainly need to include the Jar of this api in your project

Comment: I have include the jar of this api in my projuct...(if not,con not compile)